# Mac OS X Terminal Error -bash: [-f: command not found

Tags: bash, unix, command-line

Every time I start terminal I get the follow error:
`-bash: [-f: command not found`

So far it has had no negative impact but I would like to

A. Remove it

B. Figure out why it popped up recently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely in either your `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, or `.bashrc` (or a file called from one of them) file and it is occurring because there is no space between the `[` and the `-f`.

Comment: To expand on that, `[` is treated as a command, not as part of the shell syntax, and like any command you need whitespace between the command name and any arguments. (The final argument to the `[` command is `]`.)

Comment: Indeed, what's really interesting is it's actually a program, as are the other bash "commands", `if` etc.

Comment: `[` is a built-in command, though it also exists as a separate program (similar to `echo`). `if` is not a command, it's a keyword and part of the shell's syntax. Compare the output of `type [` vs. `type if`.

Comment: Ah, my mistake re `if`.